# R printing to CSV subsetted 'pivot' tables

Tags: r, csv, pivot-table, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write.csv a large number of pivot style tables (as per table b) below:

```
importer <- c("France", "Spain", "Germany", "France", "Spain", "France", "France", "France", "Germany")
exporter <- c("Peru", "Brazil", "Argentina", "Chile", "Chile", "Peru", "Peru", "Brazil", "Brazil")
goods <- c("Apples", "Wine", "Wine", "Cars", "Bananas", "Bananas", "Cars", "Bananas", "Wine")
df <-data.frame(importer, exporter, goods)
table_a <- table(df$importer, df$exporter)
write.csv(table_a,   "table_a.csv")
table_b <- table(df$importer, df$exporter, df$goods)
write.csv(table_b,   "table_b.csv")
```

But the CSV output is in the flat format [see table_b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TabKC.jpg), where as I would like to show as per the proper table [see table a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxTL8.jpg). Any ideas if/how I can achieve this?

Comment: You could use `?capture.output`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package to reshape the data into a three-way table analogous to an Excel pivot table:

```
library(reshape2)

pivot3 = dcast(df, goods + importer ~ exporter, fun.aggregate = length)

# Convert values to percent of row
pivot3[, sapply(pivot3, is.numeric)] = 
         pivot3[, sapply(pivot3, is.numeric)]/rowSums(pivot3[, sapply(pivot3, is.numeric)])

write.csv(pivot3, "table_c.csv")
```

[image]

Below is what you get if you leave the data in form of counts instead of calculating row percentages first.

[image]

Comment: that's excellent many thanks. Is there a way I can then get this data in %  of row total rather than a count? I had been using `prop.table(table_b, 1)` to achieve this previously?

Comment: See update. `sapply(pivot3, is.numeric)` selects columns with numeric values. Then we use the numeric columns to calculate the percent of row total for each row.